# Here I am trying to do a simple CRUD operation using micronaut microservices. But getting some errors

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

I am trying to do some crud operation using micornaut microservices in java.
But getting this error, Please if anyone can help me out.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.625 s <<< FAILURE! - in micronautDataAcess.MicronautDataAcessTest
[ERROR] micronautDataAcess.MicronautDataAcessTest Time elapsed: 0.623 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load a service: Unexpected error loading bean definition [micronautDataAcess.$Repository.StudentRepository$Interce
pted$Definition]: failed to access class micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted from class micronautDataAcess.$Repository.StudentRe
pository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference (micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted and micronautDataAcess.$Repository.StudentReposit
ory$Intercepted$Definition$Reference are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: Unexpected error loading bean definition [micronautDataAcess.$Repository.StudentReposit
ory$Intercepted$Definition]: failed to access class micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted from class micronautDataAcess.$Repositor
y.StudentRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference (micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted and micronautDataAcess.$Repository.Stu
dentRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted from class micronautDataAces
s.$Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference (micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository$Intercepted and micronautDataAcess.$Re
pository.StudentRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

POM FILE -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>micronautDataAcess</groupId>
  <artifactId>micronautDataAcess</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <!-- If you are building with JDK 9 or higher, you can uncomment the lines below to set the release version -->
    <!-- <release.version>8</release.version> -->
    <micronaut.version>3.1.3</micronaut.version>
    <exec.mainClass>micronautDataAcess.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=micronautDataAcess</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=micronautDataAcess</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
       <pluginRepository>
           <id>central</id>
           <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
       </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
           <id>ossrh</id>
           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

```
Controller File -
package micronautDataAcess.Controller;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import micronautDataAcess.Model.StudentModel;
import micronautDataAcess.Services.StudentServiceInterface;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller("/crud")
public class StudentController {

    @Inject
    StudentServiceInterface studentServiceInterface;

    /*Endpoint for the post method */
    @Post(value = "/add")
    @Consumes(value = "application/json")
    public HttpResponse save(@Body StudentModel crudDemoModel){
        StudentModel savedCrudDemoModel = studentServiceInterface.save(crudDemoModel);
        return HttpResponse.created(savedCrudDemoModel);
    }
    /* Endpoint for the finding */
    @Get(value = "/find")
    @Produces(value = "application/json")
    public HttpResponse findById(@NonNull Integer sid){
        Optional<StudentModel> foundModelObject = studentServiceInterface.findById(sid);
        if(foundModelObject.isPresent()){
            return HttpResponse.ok(foundModelObject);
        }
        return HttpResponse.badRequest("\'Error\':\'Id provied not found in the DB'" );
    }
}
```

```
Model - 
package micronautDataAcess.Model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "dummystudent")

public class StudentModel {
    /*All the column data*/
    /* Student id */
    @Id
    Integer sid;
    /* Student name */
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = false)
    String name;
    /* Getter method for sid */
    public Integer getSid() {
        return sid;
    }
    /* Setter method for the student id */
    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }
    /* Getter method for student name */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /* Setter method for student name */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentModel {" +
                "sid" + sid +
                "name" + name + "}";
    }


}
```

```
Repository - 
    package micronautDataAcess.Repository;
    
    import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
    import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import micronautDataAcess.Model.StudentModel;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Repository
    /* Curd repository -- will accept the 2 parameters
        1. object, char, string etc.
        2. Will accept the Integer -- that is no primitive data type.
        Here we are passing studentModel - object and Integer
     */
    public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentModel, Integer> {
    
        /* Save method will return the student object on save*/
        StudentModel save(StudentModel studentModel);
    
        /* Optional - if the entity is not found then it will return null otherwise it will return student
           entity containing all the student column data.
         */
        Optional<StudentModel> findById(Integer sid);
    
        /* Excepted the void method for the delete operation -- */
        void deleteById(Integer sid);
    
    
    
    }
```

Services -
Service Interface

```
package micronautDataAcess.Services;

import micronautDataAcess.Model.StudentModel;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface StudentServiceInterface {

    StudentModel save(StudentModel studentModel);

    Optional<StudentModel> findById(Integer sid);

    void deleteById(Integer sid);
}
```

Service Implementation

```
package micronautDataAcess.Services;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Bean;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import micronautDataAcess.Model.StudentModel;
import micronautDataAcess.Repository.StudentRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

/*Initialization of Bean and Indicating the Singleton instance */
@Singleton
@Bean
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentServiceInterface {
    /* Injecting the Student repository here in the Service Implementation */
    @Inject
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    /*Here we are overriding the StudentModel object that save the method.*/
    @Override
    public StudentModel save(StudentModel studentModel) {
        return studentRepository.save(studentModel);
    }

    /*Here we are overriding the StudentModel -- findbyid method.*/
    @Override
    public Optional<StudentModel> findById(Integer sid) {
        return studentRepository.findById(sid);
    }

    /*Here we are overriding the StudentModel -- deleteById.*/
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer sid) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(sid);
    }
}
```

Application.yml file

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronautDataAcess

datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micronautspractises
    user: root
    password: ""
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: MYSQL

flyway:
  datasources:
    packages-to-scan: 'StudentModel'
    default:
      enabled: true
```

So I have attached all the dependencies and other file used In program. If anyone can suggest a better way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Where is the test fixture you are trying to run?

Comment: Can you show what is in `micronautDataAcess.MicronautDataAcessTest`?

Comment: This is unrelated to the question but as an FYI, you probably don't need `@Bean` on  the `StudentServiceImpl` class.

Comment: We need @Bean in studentServiceImp file.

Comment: I got the solution for this problem. The error is running because of the package name. I named the package as Controller, Repository ...... etc, The Package name should be in lower case. For an example - repository, controller.